# Exporting a application from my application?

Tags: c#, polygon, vertex

The title doesn't really explain what i want but basically.

I have my application that people enter a bunch of vertex points in a polygon. Then it gives them a list of Vertex's that fit inside the polygon. What i want to do is have a executable exported from the application so they run the exported executable and it will give them the Vertex's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use System.Runtime.Emit and create an executable at runtime. 
Some Sample available there: http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/4122-How-create-exe-file-using-console-app-C.aspx

And if you need data compiled into the same executable you can define types and Fields for storing the data directly into the defined Type for instance

Comment: Thank you for showing me this, i have figured out what i need to do now

Answer (score 1):

You mean that your application would generate a single exe file which contained both program and data?

This wouldn't be easy, and it wouldn't be advisable either.

Better if your application just generates a data file which, if your application runs and sees this file, its start up behaviour is to display that data.

Then your application can write the data, and then launch a new instance of itself which will open the file and display the data.

It would still be quite an odd thing to want to do. Maybe you should explain why you need it?

Comment: Well i should have explained it better the reason i want to do this is for a extension of a game.

The application is used to generate a executable that can be ran once and modify the game to the given data.

Comment: Why not export two files, one with the data and one with the program?

Comment: I guess i could do that but i thought it would be a little weird to do it that way.

Comment: To do it in one file, you would have to write and compile your code, include that binary in another c# project, compile that, and then have the second application somehow edit the binary of the first to add the data. That would be weird, and quite hard to do.